# Can a ListActivity be inserted into a Preferences screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-preferences, android-contacts

I want to use a Preferences screen, but insert into it a ListActivity in order to display Contacts, with a checkbox, a name, and a phone number, so that users can set 1..N of their contacts as being approved for a particular operation.

Is this possible, or will I need to create my own "home-grown" or "roll-your-own" pseudo Preference screen to accomplish this?

I want to ultimately be able to loop through the ListView, saving each Contact selected (via the associated check box on its row) to either the Preferences storage or to a SQLite database.

Comment: You mean, you want to have preference activity as list activity? I didn't get what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to store Preferences that are gathered from a ListView - selected Contacts. IOW, which of the people in the Contacts list are to be included in the service the app provides? The user will select who she trusts enough to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this:](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced)